# Why the app in my desighn is diffrent from what i see in the emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently developing a basic calculator app using Android Studio. However, I have noticed an inconsistency between the UI displayed on the Design window and the one shown in the emulator. Specifically, the spacing between buttons and textViews appears to be different. This has raised some concerns, as I am worried that I may have overlooked something. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain this behavior to me. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="syntax.org.il.screenonoffexample.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonEqual"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonEqual" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDecimal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="."
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonmulti"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="*"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="6"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="9"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="8"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="="
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="-"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="5"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/newNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newNumber" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="\"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.93"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/newNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.871"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.412"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Emulator View:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/varKQ.png)

Design:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAu6F.png)

I experimented with adjusting the constraints, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Use below solution for empty button and for space issue, you can use percentage constraint using ConstraintLayout for responsiveness like widthpercent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The empty button (where the backslash should be) is because backslashes are escaped. You should have either the unicode: `\u005c` or have it like this `\\`.
2. Spacing differences could be because your emulator is different than the selected device:

[image]

Also make sure to have `Show System UI` checked:

[image]